# An Integration problem with $e^{-x^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I do this:

$$\int_0^1 (1 + e^{-x^{2}})\, dx$$

My instructor told me that this function is non integratable but then this question exists in my book's exercise problems. I have tried applying parts over the whole thing but didn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: My instinct is that this integral will have no nice closed form expression, for the simple reason that $e^{-x^2}$ has no closed form antiderivative.

Comment: The function is certainly integrable though.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be studying Taylor series at the moment....?

Comment: I am a 12th grader. I am technically not "supposed" to know it. But had to know it to solve some limits tending to infinity.

Comment: Learned error function today...

Answer (score 3):

The $e^{-x^2}$ term makes the function non-integrable *in elementary functions*. However, its integral arises so often in the study of the normal distribution that a scaled variant is called the *error function*:
$$\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{erf}(x)=\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\,dt$$
Thus the given integral may be written as $1+\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{erf}(1)$.

Comment: Okay. I dont get the concept of error function. It is defined to sort the problem of integrating $e^{-x^{2}}$ but the defination of erf(x) contains the integral again...If all of that made sense.

Comment: I performed this operation on my calculator. It gives the answer to an accuracy of 7 decimals....

Comment: Every function have to be defined somehow. The equation in this answer is in fact a definition. And it indicates you that the integral value you are searching for cannot be expressed with multiplication, addition or composition of usual functions (apart error function, of course). Also, integrable has a precise defintion, I think your teacher rather told you that there is no closed form for this integral (if you consider the error function nor being an usual function).

Comment: @Still_a_kid - did your calculator give the same answer as [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%2Berf%281%29+*+sqrt%28pi%29%2F2) ?

Comment: Yes the calculator gives "1.746824133". The same as Google.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{-x^2}$ has no elementary antiderivative, but that does not mean that $e^{-x^2}$ is not integrable. Actually $e^{-x^2}$ is an entire and non-negative function in the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, so it is very, very integrable over any measurable subset of the real line. The numerical computation of 
$$ E=\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2}\,dx $$
is an interesting task. A straightfoward approach is to exploit the entire-ness of the integrand function:
$$ E=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n!}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}.$$
The series in the RHS is both rapidly convergent and with alternating signs, so
accurate lower and upper bounds for $E$ can be derived from the partial sums. As an alternative, it is possible to check that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^3(1-x)^3 e^{-x^2}\,dx = -16+\frac{93}{16e}+\frac{297}{16}E $$
holds by integration by parts. Since the LHS is bounded between $0$ and $\frac{1}{4^3}$, the absolute error the following approximation
$$ E\approx \frac{1}{297}\left(256-\frac{93}{e}\right)$$
is less than $10^{-3}$. More accurate approximations in $\mathbb{Q}(e)$ can be derived by replacing $x^3(1-x)^3$ with $x^n(1-x)^n$ or $P_n(2x-1)$.